# Motion works on one PI, but not on another

Tags: driver, motion

I'm trying to migrate Motion from one PI (IP51) to another (IP61) and I'm running into problems getting all the functions working.

I'm testing if Motion is working by seeing if I can access the picture in firefox by placing 192.168.1.61:8070 (and :8071) in the address bar; this always works for IP51.

- Both the programs are version 3.2.12-34.

  I found this out by `dpkg -l motion | grep -E "^ii" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3` on               both machines.
- I've installed the latest Motion version on IP61 by `sudo apt-get install motion`
- I've updated my system firmware
- I installed a [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=16) driver on IP61 (motion on IP51 doesn't need this to work)
- Video drivers  installed on both are:

  `libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev libavformat53 libavformat-dev libavcodec53
  libavcodec-dev libavutil51 libavutil-dev libc6-dev zlib1g-dev
  libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libpq5 libpq-dev`

At the moment I have an un-configured motion.conf working on IP61, but when I try and introduce `stream_auth_method 2` into it, then stop and restart motion, it doesn't introduce any authentication.

I stop by: `/etc/motion$ sudo /etc/init.d/motion stop`
which gives: `Stopping motion detection daemon: motion.`

Then I start using:`/etc/motion$  LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/libuv4lext.so motion -c /etc/motion/motion.conf`

which gives:

```
[25851720] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[25851720] Unknown config option "stream_auth_method"
[25851720] Unknown config option "stream_authentication"
[25851720] Motion 3.2.12 Started
[25851720] Motion going to daemon mode
```

I installed Motion on the first pi using [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera/?ALLSTEPS). After further investigation, I'm not so sure if the `motion-mmal` version is exactly the same as the latest version. which may explain why the `stream_authentication` doesnt appear to be working on IP61.

I tried copying /usr/bin/motion from IP51 to IP61, but that didn't work either.